# ¿Cómo puedo obtener si se envio un correo o no con mail() en PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, xampp, mail

Estoy implementando un sencillo formulario de contacto, el cual envía los datos mediante `ajax` a un archivo `.php`

y aunque he modificado los parámetros para obtener un error, siempre retorna true.

```
echo mail($to,$asunto,$contenido);
```

He configurado `XAMPP` para enviar correor con SMTP de Gmail.

Comment: La función `mail()` siempre devuelve verdadero si se pudo enviar el correo, pero no hay forma de saber lo que pasa después, es decir, no puede verificar si la dirección de envío/recepción existe o si el correo llegó a bandeja de entrada o a "no deseados". Solo devolverá falso en caso de error de conexión o que la cuenta de envío/recepción sea inválida (formato).

Comment: Lo supuse, pero no entendía muy bien su funcionamiento.